# Unable to access returned data from a refetchQueries with Apollo and GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I can successfully see my refetch collecting data in the network tab. But I can see no way to retrieve that data and use it.

Below is how I am handling the refetch, I would expect the data to be part of `{(mutation, result, ...rest) => {` however these is nothing in `rest`

## < Container />

```
const onUpdateTask = ({ render }) => <Mutation
    mutation={UPDATE_TASK}
    refetchQueries={
      [
        {
          query: GET_TASKS_BY_USER_ID,
          variables: {
            assigneeId: authStorage.get().id,
          },
        },
      ]
    }
    awaitRefetchQueries={true}
  >
    {(mutation, result, ...rest) => {
      return render({ mutation, result, rest })
    }}
  </Mutation>

export default adopt({
  onUpdateTask,
});
```

## container.js

```
  <Container {...this.props}>
    {({
      onUpdateTask,
    }) => {
        console.info(onUpdateTask); //see image
    }}
  </Container>
```

[image]

As far as I can see the `data` is updated with some random Query I don't understand.

Here is the data from the query in the network tab:

```
[{"data":{"tasks":{"edges":[{"node":{"id":1,"title":"Task 11212111","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.640904+00:00","priority":"HIGH","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":2,"title":"1Task 211","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.642818+00:00","priority":"MEDIUM","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":3,"title":"Task 1111","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.644163+00:00","priority":"LOW","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":4,"title":"Cock","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.645699+00:00","priority":"MEDIUM","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":5,"title":"Task 5 balls","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.646978+00:00","priority":"LOW","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":6,"title":"Task 6","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.648202+00:00","priority":"HIGH","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":7,"title":"Task 7","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.649414+00:00","priority":"MEDIUM","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":8,"title":"Jamie","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.650558+00:00","priority":"LOW","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":9,"title":"Task 911","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.651912+00:00","priority":"HIGH","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"},{"node":{"id":10,"title":"Task 10","createdAt":"2019-03-12T12:14:21.653051+00:00","priority":"MEDIUM","dueDate":"2019-03-03T12:37:57.68033+00:00","details":"Some details","status":"OPEN","assigneeId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","creatorId":"auth0|5b448ea16d829f1018602bd6","__typename":"IssueTask"},"__typename":"IssueTasksEdge"}],"__typename":"IssueTasksConnection"}}}]
```

**Package.json**

```
"apollo-client": "^2.5.1",
"graphql": "14.0.2",
"graphql-tag": "2.10.0",
"react-apollo": "2.3.3",
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<Mutation/>` object doesn't access the response to refetchQueries for displaying data on the page - that's the job of a `<Query/>`.  The `<Mutation/>`s job is to change data and the `<Query/>`s job is to access data (from the server or cache) - thats why you are seeing the 'refetch collecting data in the network tab', the query you have recorded in `refetchQueries` is fired separately in its own call, and the data pushed into the cache for `<Query/>`s to display the updated data on screen.

When you fire a mutation, you'll get the data back that you've asked for (as you've shown at 'result.data.updateIssueByTaskId'), and that data will be pushed into the cache.  In most cases, that will be sufficient to update any `<Query/>`s on the page that are observing that data, but in some cases (such as lists, and you have added an item to the list), you may need to do some intervening (such as using `refetchQueries` or `update`)

I suspect in this case you do not need to use `refetchQueries` as you are mutating a single object, and I suspect you will be displaying that single object on the page (with the help of a `<Query/>`).  If your data is changed at the server however, you will want to keep `refetchQueries`.

Below is a small (ugly) example where I have wrapped your implementation of the Mutation in a Query that gets the data.  When you click the button it will fire the Mutation (but with no args, so I guess nothing will change?), the Mutation will then refetch the `GET_TASKS_BY_USER_ID` Query, and the `<Query/>` component will see the updated cache and so display new data in its children automatically. ( I have not used the error or loading states of the Query but have put them there so you know about them)

```
<Query query={GET_TASKS_BY_USER_ID} variables={{assigneeId: authStorage.get().id}}>
  {({ data, error, loading }) => (
    <div>
      {data && data.tasks.edges.map(edge => (
        <span>{edge.node.id}></span>
        <span>{edge.node.title}</span>
      )}
      <Container {...this.props}>
        {({onUpdateTask}) => (
          <button onClick={onUpdateTask}>Update Task </button>
        )}
      </Container>
    </div>
  )}
</Query>
```

Have a play with something like this to get your head around how they work.  You'll probably need to add some variables to the mutation so that the data changes, and then confirm it changes on screen.  Try removing the refetchQueries from your mutation and see if it still updates as you desire.

If you find that your data doesn't update like you want without refetchQueries, but it DOES when you have refetchQueries, take a look at the 'update' option for a mutation.  It is an alternative to refetchQueries that allows you to manually update the cache in a predetermined way, rather than making a round-trip call to the server for new data.

Comment: Interesting, so the problem may be that the app isn't using `cache` in the first place. I will have to look this up then. As it certainly doesn't update atm  :)

Comment: `and then push the newly returned server data into any components using that data via Queries` This is the key part that I am not sure how to do. My understanding is that this should be happening by default through apollo. I wonder if its a bug within the code?

Comment: I've updated my answer to try to make it clearer, and to provide a working example using what you've provided.  In a nutshell, you need to wrap your components in a <Query/> as that is your provider of data - refetchQueries just tells Apollo to fire off those queries (which should be existing queries consumed somewhere), update the cache, and inform any mounted `<Query/> objects to update the data they are passing into their children

Comment: Thanks again pal, I have actually wrapped them in `<Querys />` though they are nested with `adopt`. I wonder if this is the part that is playing havoc with it.

Comment: I assume you're using react-adopt, which I'm not familiar with, but what happens when you just mount the `<Mutation/>` inside the `<Query/>` without using adopt?  do you get what you need?  If the render-props approach is getting messy for you, you could also try using `compose` and the `graphql` HoC:  `export default compose(graphql(GET_TASKS_BY_USER_ID, {name: getTasks}), graphql(UPDATE_TASK, {name: updateTask}))(MyComponent)`

Comment: Ye, I will try this tomorrow sir :) Thank you so much for the help too pal.

Comment: I want to award the bounty, though I havne't had a chance to check this yet :(